# Embedding bokeh chart in reactjs frontend

Tags: reactjs, flask, bokeh

I was hoping for a sanity check on the best way to embed a Bokeh plot.

The stack is Flask primarily serving JSON APIs, and the front-end is a React.js Single Page App (SPA). So, no templates and that sort of thing.

In educating myself on [embedding plots](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html) in the [Bokeh](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/) docs there's a handful of options. But broadly:

1. Embedding plots
2. Connecting to Bokeh server as a client

First - I'm leaning towards pushing the bits from Flask to the front-end such that they are self-contained. That said, one avenue that seems to make sense to me, is to generate the JS for the plot in Flask and push to React as a remote script.

The described angle above seems preferable to alternatives of: (a) exporting HTML and baking into an iFrame, or (b) running a Bokeh client on the front-end. However, I'm speaking from a place without much experience.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion the easiest way is to use [BokehJS](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/dev_guide/bokehjs.html) on your frontend and Bokeh.embed.json_item on your backend . The typical process would be:

On your back-end (Flask in your case):

- Generate a Bokeh plot in python as you normally would. Follow any documentation online and get the visualization you’d like to display
- Pass the resulting Bokeh plot object to the json_item function call, which takes two arguments: the actual plot object and a string unique identifier. This unique ID can match the HTML ID of a DIV in your frontend, but this is not absolutely necessary.
- Dump the result as a JSON string using the standard python JSON library

A simple example would be as follows:

```
@app.route('/plot1')
def plot1():
    # copy/pasted from Bokeh Getting Started Guide
    x = linspace(-6, 6, 100)
    y = cos(x)
    p = figure(width=500, height=500, toolbar_location="below",
                     title="Plot 1")
    p.circle(x, y, size=7, color="firebrick", alpha=0.5)

    # following above points:
    #  + pass plot object 'p' into json_item
    #  + wrap the result in json.dumps and return to frontend
    return json.dumps(bokeh.embed.json_item(p, "myplot"))
```

On the frontend, make sure you import the necessary javascript and CSS files (I used a CDN for this), and then simply issue an AJAX GET request for the above endpoint. Parse the response to a json object and call **Bokeh.embed.embed_item**, similar to the below:

```
handlePlot1 = () => {
    Axios.get("http://localhost:5000/plot1")
          .then(resp =>
        window.Bokeh.embed.embed_item(resp.data, 'testPlot')
    )
  }

// in your render function
<Button
     variant="contained"
     style={{margin: 10}}
     color="primary"
     onClick={this.handlePlot1}
>
          Get Plot 1
</Button>

<div id='testPlot' className="bk-root"></div>
```

That should be enough to get you started. I wrote a [more complete blog-post about this subject](https://blog.davidvassallo.me/2019/03/11/embedding-bokeh-into-a-reactjs-app-using-bokehjs/), which also contains a link to the [github repo containing sample code](https://github.com/dvas0004/bokeh-react)

Comment: Would it also be possible to have the JS frontend hand the data for the plot to the Flask backend, which then generates the plot and hands it back to JS?

Comment: @pfincent that's what I do. Almost like above.